# res.sendFile in the callback of a sql query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, callback

I want to be able to use `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');` inside the callback of a SQL query. I can't do this because it says:

> sendFile isnt a function.

I have the SQL query SELECT * FROM table with the callback and the params as `(req, res, result)` How do I do this in a callback?

here is some code:

```js
app.post('/home', (req, res) => {
username = 'myuser';
con.query(`SELECT row FROM table`, (req, res, err, result) => {
var check = result.includes(username);
if ( check == true ) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/err.html');
} else if (check == false) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
}
});
});
```

Comment: you are using the same variable names for nested functions. are your trying to access `res` from `app.post`? or `res` from `con.query`? Stack over flow isn't a site to debug your code for you. please refer here on how to create a complete, minimal, verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a given function has a callback, the parameters of that callback are fixed. In the case of `con.query()`, the parameters are `(err, result)`, an error and a result.

What you are effectively doing is renaming the error to `req`, the result to `res`, and trying to call `res.sendFile()` which is actually calling `sendFile()` on the result of the query, which is not a thing.

You didn't need to try and pass req and res: those variables are already defined in a higher scope, so you have access to them.

Thus your snippet should be:

```
app.post('/home', (req, res) => {
    username = 'myuser';
    con.query(`SELECT row FROM table`, (err, result) => {
        var check = result.includes(username);
        if ( check == true ) {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/err.html');
        } else if (check == false) {
            res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: No problem, don't hesitate to accept/upvote the answer for people searching for it to see it.